# Recursive method checking whether a row of integers is descending: return true/false

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a recursive method in Java that returns true if a row is descending and false it does not.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work properly:

```
ArrayList<Integer> getallen = new ArrayList();
        getallen.add(500);
        getallen.add(400);
        getallen.add(300);
        getallen.add(200);
        getallen.add(100);
        getallen.add(0);

        System.out.println(isDescending(getallen));
    }

public static boolean isDescending(ArrayList<Integer> getallen) {
    if (getallen.size() >= 2) {
        if (getallen.get(0) < getallen.get(1)) {
            return false;
        } else if (getallen.size() > 0) {
            getallen.remove(0);
            return isDescending(getallen);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Your problem is with the base case. What is `isDescending` supposed to return on a list of length 1?

Comment: @Tunaki - I don't think there's some prob with that too. he's checking list is descending and a list of size can't be called descending. hence that else block should so fine.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava Actually, he removes the first element in each recursive call. So in the end, he ends up with a list of length 1 and always return false.

Comment: @Tunaki - A list of length one should just return true, I guess. It's not really clear what it should do. When I create an ArrayList with numbers: 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0, 5; it returns true for some reason.
500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0; returns false, but it shouldn't.

Comment: Then @WillShackleford answer will suit you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have unnecessary cases if the size is less than 2 you can only assume true.

Try:

```
public static boolean isDescending(ArrayList<Integer> getallen) {
    if (getallen.size() >= 2) {
        if (getallen.get(0) < getallen.get(1)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            getallen.remove(0);
            return isDescending(getallen);
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out.

Comment: Just wanted to add nearly the same solution :)
Btw. when I use List<Integer> collection, call of `remove(0)` throws an `UnsupprtedOperationException` (NetBeans 8.0.2, Java 8.0.45), so I used `subSet()` passing the parameter for further recursion.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist An `ArrayList` will never throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` in the `remove` method. Are you sure you aren't using the list returned by `Arrays.asList(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to grade this, it would get a big fat X for

- Having been fraudulently asked on stackoverflow
- Being quite inefficient (try running this test on a list of a million elements, then realise that removing element 0 in an `ArrayList` causes all elements to shift down)

Instead consider:

```
public static boolean isDescending(List<Integer> getallen) {
    return isDescending(getallen, 0);
}

public static boolean isDescending(List<Integer> getallen, int from) {
    return from >= getallen.size() - 1
            || getallen.get(from) < getallen.get(from + 1)
            && isDescending(getallen, from + 1);
}
```

Comment: I understand all elements shift down when removing the first element of the ArrayList, but I don't see why it matters for this method. The purpose of the method is to check whether the elements are in descending order. Can you explain this to me, please?

Comment: @MJM It matters not for functionality but for efficiency. In an `ArrayList`, shifting down takes as many steps as the list is long. So your algorithm has quadratic time complexity (in the list length), whereas the best algorithm (like mine) has linear complexity. That matters a lot when the data grows big. Note that `LinkedList` does not have the same disadvantage (removing takes constant time), so that would already improve your solution.

Comment: @MJM Another disadvantage of modifying the list as a side effect of the method is that the list may be shared. All aliases will have an empty list afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

How about little bit more efficient approach with logarithmic recursion depth? Just as an exercise.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> getallen = new ArrayList<Integer>();        
    getallen.add(500);
    getallen.add(400);
    getallen.add(300);
    getallen.add(200);
    getallen.add(100);
    getallen.add(0);

    System.out.println(isDescending(getallen));
}

public static boolean isDescending(List<Integer> getallen) {
    return isDescending(getallen, 0, getallen.size());
}

private static boolean isDescending(List<Integer> getallen, 
        int start, int end) {
    if (end - start <= 1)
        return true;
    if (end - start == 2) {
        return getallen.get(start) > getallen.get(start + 1);
    }
    int middle = (start + end - 1) / 2 + 1;
    return (getallen.get(middle - 1) > getallen.get(middle)) && 
            isDescending(getallen, start, middle) && 
            isDescending(getallen, middle, end);
}
```